# Capitalising every instance of a (wildcard) in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, wildcard

I'm trying to write a function that will capitalise every instance of a persons name within a string, it needs to be dynamic so the name can change. For example

"Hello Mr harrison and Mr jones" would become "Hello Mr Harrison and Mr Jones".

Is there an efficient way of doing this rather than just counting letters?

EDIT: To clarify, I will be getting strings of 4-5 sentances from the database, which is a brief description left by a company engineer. The below function formats the text so it doesn't matter if they write in full caps or no caps. However it needs to find and correct instances of Mr. (then the name of the person).

Example - if a comment is left by an engineer that reads "I HAVE FIXED MR JONES FRIDGE. MR JONES WAS HAPPY WITH THE SERVICE" - this would be converted to

"I have fixed Mr jones fridge. Mr jones was happy with the service"

EDIT: This is my function so far that formats the text.

```
function formatTextCase($string) 
// Format a string to correct upper and lower case E.g. "HELLO. goodbye." "to Hello. Goodbye."
{
// Trime whitespace
$string = trim($string);

// First format to all lower, and capitalise first letter
$string = ucfirst(strtolower($string));     

// Capitalise any letter after full stop.
$string = preg_replace_callback('/[.!?:;].*?\w/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'), $string);

// Test - please remove
//$string .= " Hello i am testing.";

// Replace any lower case I
$string = str_replace(" i ", " I ", $string);

// Now locate and capitalise any name after "Mr" eg. Mr jones to Mr Jones
What do I do here?

return $string;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: First things first, how do you know which text are names that should be capitalized

Comment: Is it every word following Mr/Mrs/etc? If so, what is the full list of titles?

Comment: If you know the wildcards, make an array of them, search the string for them and replace them with uppercase versions of themselves but otherwise it'd be hard to do

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I don't, I was using a wildcard preg_replace - but that doesn't allow me to grab the text that matches the wildcard to capitalise it.

Comment: @iainn that's right but if there is a solution that works with any of these I would be grateful as I can change to include any title.

Comment: Where do you get the names from?

Comment: @RiggsFolly its a string of text that comes from the database from our call out engineers. For example they will sometimes write "I have fixed Mr. jones table. Mr jones was happy with service".

Comment: Then show us how you get that, as that is where you can so the  case changing quite simply

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment @RiggsFolly - take it in the context of $string = "Hello Mr jones"; as this is thes string would be pulled from the database. - See the edit on my original question for how the function works so far ^^

Comment: There is no SIMPLE way of doing this! However it occurs to me that you must know the clients name from their base client record. Could you not get that and then parse this large text looking for firstname and lastname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hot one I've toiled on for you:

Code: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e844c90f0743c860a1b2a4567e5560b97672bc0e)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GkOKgI/1))

```
function uppers($m){
    $edge_cases=['De ','Di ','Du ','De La ','Van '];
    $correction=['de ','di ','du ','de la ','van '];  // reverse some fringe case names
    return str_replace($edge_cases,$correction,ucwords($m[0],"-' "));  // notice 2nd param of ucwords()
}

$sentences="i have fixed mr jones fridge.  mrs jones was happy with the service.  miss johnson-taylor told ms o'neil that everything was fabulous.  mr van larsen was less than impressed but that was a missunderstanding.  another person liked us on facebook!";
$sentences=preg_split('/[.!?]\K\s+/',$sentences); // generate array of sentences
$sentences=preg_replace_callback('/\bm(?:iss|r?s?)\b (?:de |di |du |de la |van )?[a-z]+[-\']?[a-z]*/','uppers',$sentences);  // match full names
$sentences=implode('  ',array_map('ucfirst',$sentences));  // capitalize start of sentences and rejoin sentences into a string
echo $sentences;
```

Output:

```
I have fixed Mr Jones fridge.  Mrs Jones was happy with the service.  Miss Johnson-Taylor told Ms O'Neil that everything was fabulous.  Mr van Larsen was less than impressed but that was a missunderstanding.  Another person liked us on facebook!
```

Comment: That's a fantastic implementation that covers all bases! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome...  but to be accurate there is no way to cover "all bases".  This should help you along until you have a more reliable method in place.

Comment: For the scope of the function this is above and beyond - cheers

Answer (score 0):

@iainn has a more optimal answer using regex. But an alternative solution I have come up with is, is as follows

```
$string = "Hello my name is Mr jackson and my friend is Mrs jones";

$splitString= explode(' ', $string);

foreach($splitString as $k=>$v){

  if(stristr($v, "Mr") || stristr($v, "Mrs")){
      $splitString[$k + 1] = ucfirst($splitString[$k + 1]);
  }

}

$string = implode(" ", $splitString);

echo $string;
```

Comment: Don't use strstr() to determine if a substring exists, the manual says so. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php  The 2nd white box from the top says: Note: If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.